# cudaChooseDevice function using Multi-GPU

Tags: cuda, gpu

i have Pc with 3 Gpu devices ,I want to Choose the best device which match my properties of device 1 which has only 8 multiprocessors (Note :device 0 &device 2 have 30 multiprocessors) ,but after running the following code it gives all the time device 0.

```
int main( void ) {
cudaDeviceProp prop;
int dev;
HANDLE_ERROR( cudaGetDevice( &dev ) );
printf( "ID of current CUDA device: %d\n", dev );
memset( &prop, 0, sizeof( cudaDeviceProp ) );
prop.Multiprocessorcount = 8;

HANDLE_ERROR( cudaChooseDevice( &dev, &prop ) );
printf( "ID of CUDA device which has 8 multiprocessor %d\n", dev );
HANDLE_ERROR( cudaSetDevice( dev ) );
}
```

Comment: I'm not aware of how `cudaGetDevice` actually works and under which criterion it selects the device according to `prop`. What happens if you set `prop` according to a `cudaGetDeviceProperties` of device `1`? In that case, I expect that `cudaChooseDevice` should choose exactly device `1`.

Answer (score 2):

`cudaChooseDevice` has the [following description](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1g028e5b0474379eaf5f5d54657d48600b):

> Returns in *device the device which has properties that best match *prop.

Unfortunately it seems that you disagree with the runtime API as to the definition of "best".

In that case, use your own method for choosing a device.

In fact, you have not even asked a question in this "question".  But to be clear, the algorithm used by `cudaChooseDevice` is not well documented or described. Therefore you probably shouldn't use it in cases where you desire a specific outcome or specific behavior.

Comment: Out of curiosity: has NVIDIA documented/described `cudaChooseDevice` better now (~5 years later)? Is this answer equally valid in (almost) 2019?

Comment: As of 2022 NVIDIA still has not provided ANY documentation on how cudaChooseDevice works, and as such its is probably best to avoid using it at all.